# Retrieve JCH CSS file from outside Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, css

[JCH](https://www.jch-optimize.net/) outputs the combined and compressed CSS file as:

```
/media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/gz/1/0/21258391ff538dceaca26d18cb55cb1b.css
```

Since this is a randomly generated link every time JCH refreshes the file, is there a way to retrieve the URL programmatically?

I am thinking something like this URL would allow me to reference the CSS file from outside the Joomla! environment (this is just for reference as I realize it would never work as written):

```
/index.php?option=plg_jchoptimize&view=css
```

The CSS reference is redirected to a PHP file:

```
/media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/jscss.php
```

The contents of that file are:

```
require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '/plugins/system/jch_optimize/bootstrap.php';

loadJchOptimizeClass('JchOptimizeOutput');

JchOptimizeOutput::getCombinedFile();
```

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Looking at a different approach, you could use PHP to get all the CSS files in the given directory and then import them.

Something like so:

```
$dir = 'media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/gz/1/0/*.css';

foreach (glob($dir) as $css)
{
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$css'>\n";
}
```

This is of course assuming that the website that's outside of your Joomla environment is on the same server

Comment: Great thinking outside the box! Unfortunately, these are not actual files that are stored on the server--they're just redirects to a file generated by PHP. However, that did get me thinking about calling the PHP directly. I have updated the question with info on that.

Comment: @MichaelYaeger what do you have **Combined Files Delivery** set to in the plugin options? Just so I can try and replicate this.

Comment: I'm using the "Optimum" automatic settings group

Comment: Spent a while looking through the plugin code and there are so many functions in so many files. Unfortunately I wasn't able to figure it out, but I believe that if you set **Combined Files Delivery**, you'll be able to use the code (changing the path of course) in my answer

Comment: OK, I'll give it a go and see...

Comment: I created a blank file with your #PHP code in the `<head>` and I get no CSS files output.

Comment: I do not see any **Combined Files Deliver** setting, only **Optimize CSS Delivery** which is disabled and **Manage combined file** which is "place at bottom"